# Make texts look the same size in xaml

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, user-interface, responsive

I write an XAML application and I have a problem with the size of text. How can I make the texts look complete but with the same size? (make it responsive).

This is a small example of my XAML code:

```
<!-- (0, 0) Availability -->
<Grid Grid.Row="0">
 <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
     <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform">
     <Grid Grid.Column="0">
       <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource OeeText}">Disponibilidad</TextBlock>
     </Grid>
   </Viewbox>
 <Grid Grid.Column="1">
  <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource OeeValues}">100%</TextBlock>
 </Grid>
</Grid>
```

In the Window App, the text shows as:

[image: This is an exemple of how my text looks on small screens.]

How can I make all three texts look the same size?

Thanks )

Comment: Hav you tried setting the textBox directly inside the View Box ( with the ViewBox nested into the Grid ) instead of the current implementation

Comment: Also this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30351613/responsive-textsize-in-wpf could help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may define the size of a textBox in a responsive manner using the [ViewBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.viewbox?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=windowsdesktop-7.0) Component but you have to use it inside the grid , in order to wrap the textBox Control

```
 <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform" MaxWidth="200" MaxHeight="200" MinWidth="100" MinHeight="100">
    <TextBox x:Name="MyTextBox" />
   </Viewbox>
```

You may also control the size by setting its max/min of width and height as mentioned in the docs

Comment: It has not solved the problem for me even putting the viewbox inside the grid. I keep getting "Cualidad" bigger than the rest.